# Spring Boot MVC - Do we need to use @Valid with BindingResult?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, binding

I am using Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA with Binding Results example. I have almost 100 controllers and for each Create/Update Request, we are doing below.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> saveStudent(@Valid @RequestBody StudentDto dto, BindingResult br){
    if (br.hasErrors()) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException("Wrong resource", br);
    }

    divisionService.saveStudent(dto);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Is there any way if we can centralized this logic in one place ? Can we develop listeners for the same ?

```
if (br.hasErrors()) {
    throw new InvalidRequestException("Wrong resource", br);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a reference to BindingResult in the controller? Validation exceptions will be thrown either by the Java bean Validation framework via (`@Valid`) or by any Spring Validator implementations applicable for the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a reference to the `BindingResult` in your controller.

You would only need a reference to `BindingResult` in the controller if you wanted to base some custom logic on whether or not it had errors e.g. redirect to a different view in a Rest API scenario.

Validation exceptions will be thrown either by the Java bean Validation framework (via 
you `@Valid` annotation) or by any Spring `Validator` implementations applicable for the request.

In the case of the latter a MethodArgumentNotValidException will br thrown by the framework so you can simply create a ControllerAdvice (https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) implementation which handles exceptions of this type and the `BindingResult` can be  fetched from this.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationErrorHandlingAdvice {

    /**
     * Handler for {@link MethodArgumentNotValidException}s. These are triggered by
     * Spring {@link Validator} implementations being invoked by the Spring MVC
     * controllers and returning validation errors.
     * 
     * 
     * @param ex The {@link MethodArgumentNotValidException} to be handled.
     * 
     * @return {@link Map} keyed by field to which the error is bound and with the
     *         value of the field as a value.
     */
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public @ResponseBody ValidationErrors handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, List<String>> errorMap = new TreeMap<>();

        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()) {

            if (!errorMap.containsKey(error.getField())) {
                errorMap.put(error.getField(), new ArrayList<String>());
            }

            errorMap.get(error.getField()).add(error.getDefaultMessage());
        }

        return new ValidationErrors(errorMap);
    }


    private static class ValidationErrors {
        private Map<String, List<String>> errors;

        public ValidationErrors(Map<String, List<String>> errors) {
            this.errors = errors;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public Map<String, List<String>> getErrors() {
            return errors;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BindingResult have to be followed with Valid annotation object that is bound, reason is that “if you have more objects that are bound you must know which BindingResult belongs to which object”. Indeed it provides more options/flexibility to add more details

Comment: Sorry but you are confusing different validation mechanisms. BindingResult is associated with Spring MVC Validator implementations and has nothing at all to do with validations triggered by Java Bean Validation framework

Comment: Why did you down vote a detailed and comprehensive answer? The code posted is invoked by the framework when a validation failure is triggered by a Spring Validator registred in the `@InitBinder` method. The code returns a JSON representation of the fields in error.